# Is it possible to listen for an event from an app, from outside of that app

Tags: c++, c, events, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I need to listen for touch events from a specific app(in blackberry 10 os). I am planning to write another app which does this. Is this possible?

APP A- the app which exists
APP B- The app i am going to write

what sort of modification do i need to do for the APPA to make this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Cascades environment touch events are passed as SIGNALS which are received by SLOTS. This message passing implementation is bound to the threading model and does not have a direct inter process counterpart. Theoretically you could implement something on top of the QNX message passing system, or on top of BlackBerry Platform Services (BPS). This might be necessary if you need the kind of performance available within a single application.

The other option is to use the invokation API that BlackBerry provides in Cascades. This is a very flexible inter-process communications protocol but is inherently synchronous. Normally UI focus moves from the invoking process to the invoked process, this does not sound like what you want. The invoked process can return immediately after receiving the invokation and before posting any UI elements, but there is still the overhead of launching the invoked process, at least in the first instance, and context switching in other instances.

It might be more fruitful to be more specific about what you are really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I would start looking at [Starting a process](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.getting_started/topic/s1_procs_starting_a_process.html) if you haven't all-ready.

Answer (score 0):

Probably NOT !

Your app can only listen to touch events in your app and cannot spy on other apps.

Comment: What if I Invoke another app within a thread from my app? if so would it be possible?

Comment: I don't think it matters.. only one app is visible at a time and only that visible app receives the touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. This would be a major security flaw...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The question asks "Is this possible?" The answer to that question is "No".